# can someone with fair knowledge of jQuery help me with this.?

Tags: jquery

I cant make some logical sense of what happend here, can some one help me please??

```js
// heynow.js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // on the checkbox disable it right away
  $('#agree').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

  //on the terms box add a scroll function
  $('#terms').scroll(function() {  

    // textareheight equals scrollheight   not accurate
    var textareaheight = $(this).[0].scrollHeight;

    // scrollheight equals scrollheight – the innerheight  which is more accurate and dynamic
    var scrollheight = textareaheight - $(this).innerHeight();

    // scrolltop equals  scrolltop returning where are you
    var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

    // if where you at equals the total height
    if (scrolltop == scrollheight) {

      // then enable the checkbox
      $('#agree').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

---

```html
<!-- html file -->
<p><textarea id="terms">lots of text for a scroll avail</textarea></p>
<p><input id="agree" type="checkbox" /> I Agree</p>
```

Comment: Are you coding in Word 2010?

Comment: your code is having error check this http://jsfiddle.net/dht8R/

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple. It disables checkbox and keeps it that way until You scroll down to the end of the content. It's nothing special :) You can see it on pages where You have to read the license before accepting it.